# loading labview project killing hg id

Tags: mercurial, labview

I have a labview project with a mercurial repo.

If I update to the tip.

```
hg up tip 
hg id  
93cc...
```

I then load project.lvproj into labview2013 then

```
hg id
000000000000
```

I expect 93cc..., maybe 93cc...+.
also the parent gets set to -1.

Inspection of .hg folder shows that when labview is loaded, a file "dirstate" is deleted, and a new file "dirstate-55eed402" is created.

I haven't figured out why dirstate is being deleted, but knowing how to rebuild it is helpful:

```
hg debugrebuildstate -r tip
```

Comment: Could labview be touching the .hg folder inside the repo? If it's editing the contents of the .hg folder it might explain what you're seeing.

Comment: I can't think of a reason LabVIEW would be doing that but you might want to check in the Files tab of the LabVIEW project explorer that none of the files in .hg are being treated as part of the project. Also that you've set hg to ignore the .lvlps and .aliases files.

Comment: I don't know anything about LabVIEW, but what you're seeing is the result of what an `hg update null` would do; this is usually done to set a repository to a no-checkout state (`null` is the pseudo-revision that is the ancestor of the first revision, and is equivalent to '000000000.....0').